# How to setup a MongoDB replica set in EC2 US-WEST with only two availability zones

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, replicaset, availability-zone

We are setting up a **MongoDB replica set** on **Amazon EC2** in the **us-west-1** region.

This region only has two availability zones though. My understanding is that MongoDB must have a majority to work correctly. If we create 2 servers in zone `us-west-1b` and one server in `us-west-1c` this will not provide high availability if the entire `us-west-1b` goes down right? How is this possible? What is the recommended configuration?

Comment: A majority needs to be present for a primary to be successfully elected and become writable.  A stranded node would remain read-only if it already was, and would make itself read-only if it wasn't already, when the split occurred.  Perhaps adding 2 arbiters in us-west-2?

Answer (score 0):

Having faced a similar challenge we looked at a number of possible solutions:

Put an Arbiter in another region:

Secure the connection either by using a point to point VPN between the regions a routing the traffic across this connection.

or

Give each server an E-IP and DNS name and use some combination of AWS security groups, IPTables and SSL to ensure connections are secure.

AWS actually have a whitepaper on this not sure how old it is though http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf

Alternatively you could allow the application to fall back to a read-only state until your servers come back on-line (not the nicest of options though)

Hope this helps